# How to display badges with username?

Tags: 6, users

How can i display the badges with username like stackexchange? I am using D6 and [user badge](https://drupal.org/project/user_badges) and [userpoints](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints) modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two modules you can try both of which integrate with user badges but will need a little more customization to get it right. Try the [user_picture_block](https://drupal.org/project/user_picture_block) module:

> Create just one block with the logged on user's picture, if he/she has one. In addition, User titles, points and badges are also displayed, if there are any.

[image]

Also, there is the [author_pane](https://drupal.org/project/author_pane) module which also has built-in integration with user_badges:

[image]

Comment: It is an alternative but a good option. I used the  "user_picture_block" module. But badge images do not come. So, how can i do this?

Comment: I used "Author Pane" module which is also a good option. Actually, I had used this module before. But did not know it is integrated with "user badges" module.